# Sticky footer, small gap between footer and bottom of page

Tags: html, css

I am using sticky footer. I noticed that on pages where the content does not reach the bottom completely there is a small gap between the footer and the bottom of the page.

Example of short content with footer gap: http://karenrubkiewicz.com/martin/published.html
Example of long content with no footer gap: http://karenrubkiewicz.com/martin/people.html

Below is my coding.
Thanks in advance!

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">

SITE CONTENT HERE

<div class="push"></div>
</div> <!-- END WRAPPER -->

    <section id="footer">
    <div class="left">
        <li><a href="about.html">[about]</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">[contact]</a></li>
        <li><a href="pdf.html">[pdf]</a></li>
        <li><a href="imprint.html">[Imprint]</a></li>
    </div>

    <div class="right">
        <li><a href="http://www.linkedin.com/home" target="_blank"><div class="linkedin"></div></a></li>
        <li><a href=" http://martinkess.tumblr.com/" target="_blank"><div class="tumblr"></div></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.behance.net/martinkess" target="_blank"><div class="behance"></div></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/martin.kess.7?fref=browse_search" target="_blank"><div class="facebook"></div></a></li>
    </div>
 </section>
```

CSS

```
html, body{
height:100%;
}

body{
overflow-x:hidden;
}

.wrapper {
overflow-x:hidden;
min-height: 100%;
height: auto !important;
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto -50px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
}

#footer .push {
height: 50px; /* .push must be the same height as .footer */
}

#footer{
position: absolute;
height: 50px;
left:0;
width:100%;
min-width:1300px;
background:#000;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still have margin on body. You should add:

```
body{
    margin:0;
}
```

I recommend you to put some css reset code. To unify common browser settings for elements (this would prevent such situation also).